# javascript point position issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript sample from this page and I am using IE 7 on Windows 7,

http://nofunc.org/AJAX_Star_Rating

For this sample, I am confused about this statement of function document.onmousemove,

```
var p = abPos($('star' + n))
    , x = XY(e)
    , oX = x.X - p.X
    , oY = x.Y - p.Y; s
tar.num = o.id.substr(4);
```

My specific confusion is if I scroll down the browser horizontal bar (see the screen snapshot below), for the 5th star (I moves my mouse over 5th star to measure the positions), x.Y descrease, but p.Y never changes. Any ideas what is wrong?

Screen snapshot to show this error, http://i52.tinypic.com/4vhi7c.png

For example, before I scroll down the browser horizontal bar, for the 5th star, x.Y/p.Y are 492/477, but after I scroll down, x.Y/p.Y are 380/477.

document.body.scrollTop is always 0 even if scroll down, I have used the below alert to debug.

EDIT 1:

```
    document.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var n = star.num;

        alert (event.clientY + ' ' + document.body.scrollTop);
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if you are learning javascript then please, please go and install Google Chrome. It is a far better environment to be learning javascript in than IE7, its builtin debugging and developer tools are a far better way to get to grips with javascript.

Comment: Thanks andynormancx! What debugging tools in Chrome do you mean?

Comment: Mainly I mean the Javascript console you get to by hitting ctrl-shift-J. That allows you to run bit of Javascript interactively, examine the document structure in detail, set break points, examine variable contents,  look at call stacks, run profiles to time your code, examine which resources are being downloaded etc etc

Comment: To be fair, recent versions of IE (and other browsers like Firefox and Safari also have some similar tools available), but if I remember correctly IE7 doesn't.

Comment: Also vital to easily debugging webpages and Javascript is the "right click -> Inspect Element" functionality in Chrome. This allows to to jump straight into the console and highlights the HTML element that you right clicked on. You can then even set break points on the HTML elements themselves, so you get alerted when their properties get changed, element inserted/delete etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From quick look in the code, abPos returns the absolute position of the element in the document, regardless of the scroll.

XY function returns the "actual" position, with the scroll position (i.e. how much pixels the user has scrolled) already integrated in the return value.

So when you scroll, "p" values won't change while "x" values will change indeed.

Why do you ask? From looking at the screenshot I couldn't see anything wrong.

Anyway, you mean vertical scroll, not horizontal.

Comment: Yes Shadow, I mean vertical scroll. Thanks for your reply. My question is, how to get the absolute position of x.Y? I want x.Y to be increase as p.Y increases when we scroll vertically down.

Comment: @George2 you can add it manually.. just add the value of `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to p.Y when you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks Shadow! But I tried that document.body.scrollTop is always 0. Please refer to the EDIT 1 section of my original post for how I get its always 0 value.

Comment: You mean documentElement.scrollTop?

Comment: And also documentElement.scrollTop is also undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: @George2 it's written in my very first comment here, here it is again: `document.documentElement.scrollTop` :)

Comment: Thanks Shadow, question answered!

Comment: Cheers @George2 glad I could be of help. :-)